# Cannot find Cuda while compiling example-app using Libtorch c++ library

Tags: cmake, cuda, c++14, libtorch

I have Cuda installed on my computer using void linux and I have the following paths set
I am trying to setup libtorch following instructions found in this
link: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html

The cmake version I am using is

```
> cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

My cuda version is 12.1
So, I downloaded libtorch that supports 12.1
which can be found under nightly in this link: https://pytorch.org/
The operating system is linux. I did not understand the difference between cxx11 and the precxx11 so I chose to go with cxx11 version randomly.
The command i used to download is

```
wget https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/nightly/cu121/libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-latest.zip
```

Environment variable that I have set:

```
> echo $CUDA_HOME
/usr/local/cuda
```

```
> echo $PATH     
/home/dirtyv/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/dirtyv/.cargo/bin:/home/dirtyv/.bin:/home/dirtyv/Codes/Website/emsdk:/home/dirtyv/Codes/Website/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/home/dirtyv/Codes/Website/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

There are lots of strings in the path variables but /usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin is one of them. To show that CUDA is working I can run `nvcc --version`

```
> nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Apr__3_17:16:06_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.105
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32688072_0
```

```
> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-12.1/lib64
```

My main.cpp file contains the following code

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3});
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
}
```

The CMakeList.txt file I am using contains the following lines same as in the example found in the link

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
#COMPIER
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
#FLAGS
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")
#PROJECT
project(Example)
#Required Package
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
#RUNTIME OUTPUT DIR
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
#EXECUTABLE CONFIG
add_executable(MLA ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MLA "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET MLA PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

The bash command I am using to compile the solution is

```
cd ./build/ && cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/Codes/C_C++/C++/example/thirdparty/libtorch .. && cmake --build . --config Release
```

When I run this bash command I get the following error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found version "12.1")
CMake Warning at thirdparty/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake:31 (message):
  Caffe2: CUDA cannot be found.  Depending on whether you are building Caffe2
  or a Caffe2 dependent library, the next warning / error will give you more
  info.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  thirdparty/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:87 (include)
  thirdparty/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


CMake Error at thirdparty/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:91 (message):
  Your installed Caffe2 version uses CUDA but I cannot find the CUDA
  libraries.  Please set the proper CUDA prefixes and / or install CUDA.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  thirdparty/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I checked this web-page: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/23066 for the solution and realized I already have the proper environment variables set.

If anyone knows why cmake still outputs `Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (found version "12.1")` please let me know and how to solve it

Comment: That would be a detail that should be in the question. However, the CMake output clearly shows it found 12.1  and that it thinks that isn’t the correct version for the version of Caffe 2 within the libtorch tree you are trying to build against.  Are you really sure that you don’t have another libtorch somewhere other than the nightly build you claim you are using?

Comment: No I only downloaded one because I had cuda 12.1 installed before hand and I downloaded a version that matches the toolkit. I will edit the question and add that detail

Comment: I had a different understanding of the cmake output. I thought that it found the required version of executable however cmake find script is unable to resolve the following variables `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR, CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS, CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY`

Comment: What version of CMake are you using. Generally I would use >=3.18 for good CUDA support. For CUDA 12 using one of the latest versions might work even better.

Comment: I don’t believe that is correct. The error is that the automatic search logic for the CUDA toolkit found 12.1, but that isn’t what is needed, and because there is no manual variable settings to help CMake find  the version of the toolkit required, the build stops. I abhor CMake and never use it unless there is no other choice, so I might be wrong